# What semantics does clang use for CXXBindTemporaryExpr

Tags: clang++

I'm trying to understand how clang applies semantics to `CXXBindTemporaryExpr`. The documentation says that these nodes note temporary objects that need to be destructed.

To try this out, I have the following piece of code:

```cpp
int x  = 0;
struct P {
    P(int) {}
    P(int,int) {}
    ~P() { ++x; }
};

P by_val() {
    return P(1);
}

int main() {
    P a = by_val();
    return x;
}
```

For this, clang++ (with -std=c++17) generates the following AST.

```sh
|-FunctionDecl 0x29bde08 <line:8:1, line:10:1> line:8:3 used by_val 'P ()'
| `-CompoundStmt 0x29be158 <col:12, line:10:1>
|   `-ReturnStmt 0x29be148 <line:9:5, col:15>
|     `-ExprWithCleanups 0x29be130 <col:12, col:15> 'P'
|       `-CXXFunctionalCastExpr 0x29be108 <col:12, col:15> 'P' functional cast to struct P <ConstructorConversion>
|         `-CXXBindTemporaryExpr 0x29be0e8 <col:12, col:15> 'P' (CXXTemporary 0x29be0e0) <-- 1
|           `-CXXConstructExpr 0x29be0b0 <col:12, col:15> 'P' 'void (int)'
|             `-IntegerLiteral 0x29bdef0 <col:14> 'int' 1
`-FunctionDecl 0x29be1c0 <line:12:1, line:15:1> line:12:5 main 'int ()'
  `-CompoundStmt 0x29be448 <col:12, line:15:1>
    |-DeclStmt 0x29be400 <line:13:5, col:19>
    | `-VarDecl 0x29be298 <col:5, col:18> col:7 a 'P' cinit
    |   `-ExprWithCleanups 0x29be3e8 <col:11, col:18> 'P'
    |     `-CXXBindTemporaryExpr 0x29be3c8 <col:11, col:18> 'P' (CXXTemporary 0x29be3c0) <---- 2
    |       `-CallExpr 0x29be3a0 <col:11, col:18> 'P'
    |         `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x29be388 <col:11> 'P (*)()' <FunctionToPointerDecay>
    |           `-DeclRefExpr 0x29be340 <col:11> 'P ()' lvalue Function 0x29bde08 'by_val' 'P ()'
    `-ReturnStmt 0x29be438 <line:14:5, col:12>
      `-IntegerLiteral 0x29be418 <col:12> 'int' 0
```

The node `CXXBindTemporaryExpr` occurs twice in the AST, but neither should generate a call to the destructor because the object that is marked as a temporary is not actually a temporary, it is constructed directly into the `a` in main (if I understand the C++ semantics correctly, as of C++17 there is no temporary to destroy). Indeed, this is confirmed by compiling and running the program (which returns 0, as noted the only destructor call happens after the return).

So why does clang generate these nodes in the first place? And is there a way to determine when these nodes should generate destructor calls and when they shouldn't?

Originally, I thought that the `CXXFunctionalCastExpr` is hiding a call to the copy-constructor, but that isn't true because if you print the conversion function, it is a call to `P(int)` which seems to imply that it is a node representing syntactic sugar with no semantic information.

*My hypothesis is that this node simply stores information necessary for generating calls to destructors in exceptional cases, that it doesn't mean anything from a semantics point of view. For example, it might be needed for exception handling, though I don't know where.*

Comment: The program returns 0 for me https://wandbox.org/permlink/bdfeUh0FgUNfTjvh as it should do.  The lvalue-to-rvalue conversion on `x` occurs prior to the destructor is called on `a`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I must have misread the output.

Answer (score 0):

The relationship between Clang's AST and what actually goes on in the C++ standard is essentially whatever Clang wants it to be. The standard doesn't specify an AST; it specifies the behavior of a set of code. How you get from that code to the compiled output that exhibits that behavior is the job of the C++ implementation. If an implementation wants to build an AST on the way there, so be it.

Do not confuse the AST with the actual compiler's output.

So, what does `CXXBindTemporaryExpr` mean? It means whatever Clang needs for it to mean in order for Clang to implement the C++ standard. My guess is that it means that the child nodes of that node represent some form of prvalue.

Does the presence of two of these "temporaries" mean that Clang violates the specification? No. Because the standard doesn't define an AST. If Clang is going to implement the standard, and as part of this process it builds an AST, it's the job of the code processing the AST to follow the rules of the standard. If it sees a `CXXBindTemporaryExpr` being returned, then it should know to apply the rules of guaranteed elision when generating code. If it sees a `CXXBindTemporaryExpr` wrapping a function call, then it should again apply the rules of guaranteed elision where applicable.

Comment: I agree with this, this is less a C++ question and more a clang++ question. I'm trying to understand how the codegen portion of clang interprets a `CXXBindTemporaryExpr` node.